# Swift LocalNotification last fireDate

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an app that should sent a local notification ever day for 21 days, but then it should stop sending for a week. I know I can set a fireDate and I can set a repeatInterval, but is there any way to set something like a last fireDate? Or is there a function which is fired every time a local notification is send?
I know there is a function called if the app starts from a notification but thats not my solution, because if the user don't opens the app the notifications will be send further.
Can anybody please help me?

Thats my code so far

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Take Pill"
    notification.alertAction = "open"
    notification.fireDate = _notificationTime
    notification.repeatInterval = .day
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    notification.userInfo = ["title": "takePill", "UUID": "takePill"]

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: "but then it should stop sending" What does "then" mean in that sentence? _When_ should it stop? The concept "every day" has no end. (Also UILocalNotification is deprecated and does not work very well in iOS 10.)

Comment: It should send the notification 21 days long and should stop then for a week

Comment: Fix your _question_ so that it correctly states the problem, please.

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are something that the system sends to the user on your behalf. Your app is not "in the loop". The system always exists and therefore can always send the notification — but your app can be suspended or even terminated. If you are going to use local notifications, therefore, you must consider the possibility that your app will *never* run in the future while the system is doing all this work for you.

Thus, a moment's thought will show that the only configuration that does what you are describing is to schedule 21 notifications, each set to fire on each subsequent day. There are *only* 21 notifications, so on the 22nd day, nothing happens because there is no notification scheduled for that day.

(But this limitation should also give you pause and make you wonder whether local notifications are the way to accomplish this.)